# Salvar/ manter estado (selecionado ou não selecionado) do checkbox após fechar o navegador

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

Estou fazendo uma página que tem uma tabela com valores vindos do banco de dados. Ela tem 4 colunas e mais de 300 linhas. 
Uma coluna tem um `checkbox` para cada linha, a outra tem o nome de um objeto e as outras duas colunas têm características desse objeto.
Eu preciso que depois que a pessoa marcar um `checkbox`, ele apareça marcado mesmo se ela fechar o navegador. Isso pode ser feito em php?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
  // INICIAR SESSÃO
  //=================================================================
  if (isset('$_SESSION'['msg'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['msg'];
      unset ($_SESSION['msg']);
  }
  
  
  // TRAZER DADOS DO BANCO
  //=================================================================
  $result_cruzamentos = "SELECT * FROM polo_pi_02";
  $resultado_cruzamentos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cruzamentos);
  
  
  // EXIBIÇÃO DA TABELA
  //===================================================       
  echo '<div id="inicio" class="row valign-wrapper">';
      echo '<div id="admin" class="col s12 ">';
          echo '<form action="../php/action_handler.php" method="POST">';
              echo '<div class="center-align card material-table">';
                  echo '<div class="table-header">';
                      echo '<span class="table-title">GOIÁS SUL/ NORTE - FLUXO TARDIO</span>';
                      echo '<div class="actions">';
                          echo '<a href="#" class="search-toggle btn-flat nopadding"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>';
                      echo '</div>';
                  echo '</div>';
                  echo '<table id="datatable" class="highlight display centered">';                               
                      echo '<thead>';
                          echo '<tr>';
                              echo '<th class="cor_0">Status</th>';                                    
                              echo '<th class="cor_0">Rank</th>';
                              echo '<th class="cor_0">Nome</th>';
                              echo '<td class="cor_1">PCC</td>';                                        
                          echo '</tr>';
                      echo '</thead>';


                      // TBODY
                      // ================================================================
                      echo '<tbody>';
                      // Armazena os dados da consulta em um array associativo
                      while($row_cruzamento = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_cruzamentos)){
                          echo '<tr>';

                              // COLUNA 1: CHECKBOX
                              //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              echo '<td class="checkbox">';
                                 echo '<input type="checkbox" id="check_id_'.$row_cruzamento['pagina_cruz'].'" value="'.$row_cruzamento['pagina_cruz'].'" name="checados[]" class="filled-in" />';
                                 echo '<label for="check_id_'.$row_cruzamento['pagina_cruz'].'"></label>';
                              echo '</td>';  

                              // COLUNA 2: RANKING
                              //-------------------------------------------------------------------------                         
                              echo '<td>'.$row_cruzamento['cruz_id'].'</td>';

                              // COLUNA 3: NOME
                              //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              echo '<td class="large">';
                                  echo '<div>';
                                      echo '<p>'.$row_cruzamento['g1'].'</p>';
                                      echo '<p>'.$row_cruzamento['g2'].'</p>';
                                  echo '</div>';
                              echo '</td>';

                              // COLUNA 4: NOTA
                              //------------------------------------------------------------------------                          
                              echo '<td>';
                                  echo '<div class="change_color">';
                                      echo '<p id="g1fenbvpcc">'.$row_cruzamento['g1_fen_bv_pcc_nota'].'</p>';
                                      echo '<p>'.$row_cruzamento['g2_fen_bv_pcc_nota'].'</p>';
                                  echo '</div>';
                              echo '</td>';                                    
                          echo '</tr>';
                      }
                      echo '</tbody>';
                  echo '</table>';
              echo '</div><!-- END MATERIAL-TABLE -->';
  
              // BOTÃO PARA SALVAR ESTADO DO CHECKBOX
              echo '<center>';
              echo '<div>';
                  echo '<a class="save waves-effect waves-light btn indigo darken-4 tooltiped" title="Salva o estado de seleção dos cruzamentos"><input type="submit" value="SALVAR"></a>';            
              echo '</div>';
              echo '</center>';
    
              echo '</form>';
          echo '</div><!-- END COL s12 -->';
      echo '</div><!-- END ROW -->';
  
  ?>
  </body>
  <html>
```

Comment: Posta seu código para ajuda-la melhor. Seguinte nesta sua ideia. Vc pode fazer assim: Quando um usuário clicar no checkbox vc submit o formulário ou via ajax, vc atualiza sua base de dados com um flag (checkbox marcado ou não). Com isto, mesmo fechando o navegador vc terá a informação no banco de dados e poderá retorno o valor do check marcado depois.

Comment: *"marcado mesmo se ela fechar o navegador"*, neste caso precisa salvar em algum repositório, um banco de dados por exemplo, ou nos cookies do computador do usuário, mas isso pode ser apagado, então a melhor opção seria saber num banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você vai precisar utilizar SESSION (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.examples.basic.php) ou COOKIE (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php)